# How to separate a Python list into two lists, according to some aspect of the elements

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[[8, "Plot", "Sunday"], [1, "unPlot", "Monday"], [12, "Plot", "Monday"], [10, "Plot", "Tuesday"], [4, "unPlot", "Tuesday"], [14, "Plot", "Wednesday"], [6, "unPlot", "Wednesday"], [1, "unPlot", "Thursday"], [19, "Plot", "Thursday"], [28, "Plot", "Friday"], [10, "unPlot", "Friday"], [3, "unPlot", "Saturday"]]
```

I want to separate it into two lists according the `Plot` and `unPlot` values, resulting:

```
list1=[[8, "Plot", "Sunday"], [12, "Plot", "Monday"], ...]
list2=[[1, "unPlot", "Monday"], [4, "unPlot", "Tuesday"], ...]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with basic list comprehension:

```
>>> [ x for x in l if x[1] == "Plot" ]
[[8, 'Plot', 'Sunday'], [12, 'Plot', 'Monday'], [10, 'Plot', 'Tuesday'], [14, 'Plot', 'Wednesday'], [19, 'Plot', 'Thursday'], [28, 'Plot', 'Friday']]
>>> [ x for x in l if x[1] == "unPlot" ]
[[1, 'unPlot', 'Monday'], [4, 'unPlot', 'Tuesday'], [6, 'unPlot', 'Wednesday'], [1, 'unPlot', 'Thursday'], [10, 'unPlot', 'Friday'], [3, 'unPlot', 'Saturday']]
```

Or with `filter` if you fancy functional programming:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x[1] == "Plot", l)
[[8, 'Plot', 'Sunday'], [12, 'Plot', 'Monday'], [10, 'Plot', 'Tuesday'], [14, 'Plot', 'Wednesday'], [19, 'Plot', 'Thursday'], [28, 'Plot', 'Friday']]
>>> filter(lambda x: x[1] == "unPlot", l)
[[1, 'unPlot', 'Monday'], [4, 'unPlot', 'Tuesday'], [6, 'unPlot', 'Wednesday'], [1, 'unPlot', 'Thursday'], [10, 'unPlot', 'Friday'], [3, 'unPlot', 'Saturday']]
```

I personally find list comprehensions much clearer. It's certainly the most "pythonic" way.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = [[8, "Plot", "Sunday"], [1, "unPlot", "Monday"], [12, "Plot", "Monday"], [10, "Plot", "Tuesday"], [4, "unPlot", "Tuesday"], [14, "Plot", "Wednesday"], [6, "unPlot", "Wednesday"], [1, "unPlot", "Thursday"], [19, "Plot", "Thursday"], [28, "Plot", "Friday"], [10, "unPlot", "Friday"], [3, "unPlot", "Saturday"]]

res = {'Plot':[],'unPlot':[]}
for i in data: res[i[1]].append(i)
```

This way you iterate the list once

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
yourList=[[8, "Plot", "Sunday"], [1, "unPlot", "Monday"], [12, "Plot", "Monday"], [10, "Plot", "Tuesday"], [4, "unPlot", "Tuesday"], [14, "Plot", "Wednesday"], [6, "unPlot", "Wednesday"], [1, "unPlot", "Thursday"], [19, "Plot", "Thursday"], [28, "Plot", "Friday"], [10, "unPlot", "Friday"], [3, "unPlot", "Saturday"]]
plotList=[]
unPlotList=[]

for i in yourList:
    if "Plot" in i:
        plotList.append(i)
    else:
        unPlotList.append(i)
```

or shorter with comprehension:

```
plotList = [i for i in yourList if "Plot" in i]
unPlotList = [i for i in yourList if "unPlot" in i]
```

Comment: ezdazuzena's got it... that should work... just make sure to define plotlist & unplotlist as empty lists first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions, e.g.

```
# old_list elements should be tuples if they're fixed-size, BTW
list1 = [(X, Y, Z) for X, Y, Z in old_list if Y == 'Plot']
list2 = [(X, Y, Z) for X, Y, Z in old_list if Y == 'unPlot']
```

If you want to traverse the input list only once, then maybe:

```
def split_list(old_list):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for X, Y, Z in old_list:
        if Y == 'Plot':
            list1.append((X, Y, Z))
        else:
            list2.append((X, Y, Z))
    return list1, list2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply go through the list, and check if the value is "Plot" like this:

```
for i in List:
  if i[1]=="Plot":
    list1.append(i)
  else:
    list2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper function for the general case of partitioning a list in two:

```
def partition(iterable, condition):
        def partition_element(partitions, element):
            (partitions[0] if condition(element) else partitions[1]).append(element)
            return partitions
        return reduce(partition_element, iterable, ([], []))
```

For example:

```
>>> partition([1, 2, 3, 4], lambda d: d % 2 == 0)
([2, 4], [1, 3])
```

Or in your case:

```
>>> partition(your_list, lambda i: i[1] == "Plot")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
l = [[8, "Plot", "Sunday"], [1, "unPlot", "Monday"], [12, "Plot", "Monday"], [10, "Plot", "Tuesday"], [4, "unPlot", "Tuesday"], [14, "Plot", "Wednesday"], [6, "unPlot", "Wednesday"], [1, "unPlot", "Thursday"], [19, "Plot", "Thursday"], [28, "Plot", "Friday"], [10, "unPlot", "Friday"], [3, "unPlot", "Saturday"]]

list1 = [x for x in l if x[1] == "Plot"]

list2 = [x for x in l if x[1] == "unPlot"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) command:

```
list1 = filter(lambda x: x[1] == "Plot", list)
list2 = filter(lambda x: x[1] == "unPlot", list)
```